# Java: Include "this" parameter or let it be implied

Tags: java, standards

Is there a Java recommendation or industry best-practice suggestion for including, or not including, the `this` parameter when it isn't explicitly necessary?

For instance, assuming there are no naming clashes between instance variables and local variables, is it preferential to use

`this.someParam`

or simply

`someParam`

and when calling methods that are in the same class is it preferential to use

`this.someMethod()`

or

`someMethod()`

The argument in favor of the former is that it makes the code more explicit. The argument in favor of the latter is that it makes the code cleaner.

I'm curious if there is any documentation out there that recommends one way or another (I can't find any, google searches with the word `this` are obviously tricky) or if it is simply a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

On the merits of explicit versus cleaner: Excluding "this." is no doubt less text character "noise" (albeit small) in source file.  The "this." explicitness would be helpful for example if using a small text viewer when looking at a method with many lines of code (should that be the case anyway?). So at best the explicitness has limited usefulness - especially as modern IDEs highlight instance variables. I am of the opinion of excluding "this." as code style.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to prefer one or the other. It's a matter of opinion.

My opinion is that you should only use `this` if needed. There are some situations when you have to use this, such as if a local variable has the same name as an instance variable. It happens a lot in my constructors:

```
public MyClass(String s, int i) {
    this.s = s;
    this.i = i;
}
```

If you are working on a team, I recommend coming up with a strategy you all agree with, so you don't waste too much time reformatting each others code. Also, for me, it's pretty annoying to look at code that uses `this` too much (such as that generated by [JD](http://jd.benow.ca)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is a "wrong" answer here.  However, in my 15+ years writing Java, the convention that I have seen is to NOT include "this" unless it is necessary.

You can minimize confusion by naming variables in a consistent way.  There are several good convention documents out there.  Pick one and follow it.  Some examples:

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html
https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html
http://www.javaranch.com/style.jsp

Answer (score 1):

As for:

- parameters/attributes - I always suggest using consistent approach throughout the code. In most cases all automatically generated getters and setters of Java classes need to use `this` to distinguish parameter name from actual object attribute. Consistency is then a good reason to use `this` for instance variables throughout the code. Sample setter which uses `this` to avoid ambiguity:

  ```
  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
  ```
- methods - `this.someMethod()` is just longer than `someMethod()` and does not provide any benefit over the shorter `someMethod()`. If we call the latter, it is already known that we are in fact calling `this.someMethod()`. There is no ambiguity in calling just `someMethod()` like it is for parameters, so I would discourage the use of `this.someMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no common guidelines for all Java developers in the world defining good practices for using `this`. I'd rather follow the guidelines used in your company/project, or, if there are none, your own ways of writing well-read code.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a best-practice suggestion. Most teams simply have their own coding style.

Personally, I try to use use `this` for all my instance variables, but tend to avoid it for methods.